# Limiting Number of Decimals of an Output in Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, ibaction

I have a few actions in xcode where the number of decimals in the output value needs to be limited to 3 decimal places out. What do I need to add to my code to achieve this task?

Here is an example of one of my actions:

```
- (IBAction)calculateMolarity:(id)sender {
float ourValue = [[_calcTextFieldNumOne text] floatValue]   /[ [_calcTextFieldTwo text]      floatValue];

NSNumber *ourNum =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:ourValue];

[_outputOfMolarity setText:[ourNum stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.03f", ourNum];
```

> here `%.03f` tells the formatter that you will be formatting a float
>   (%f) and, that should be rounded to three places, and should be padded
>   with 0's.

but you can do directly with your float ourValue like this

```
 NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.03f", ourValue];
```

there is no need to convert your float value to NSNumber

you can use `"%.3f"` or `"%.03f"`, no matter both gives same fromat

```
@"%.3f"  = 1234.567
@"%.03f" = 1234.567 // which is equal to @"%.3f"
```

Comment: Thanks but it appears that there is an issue with the formattedNumber variable and the .03f in the "%.03f" . Any thoughts?